# JMeter starting next thread loop using setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In JMeter5.1 I am using a beanShell pre-processor to achieve following

1. If previous request fails wait for 5 sec
2. Start next thread loop

But it is not restarting the next loop. Searched everywhere on the web, could not find anything working. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction;

if(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok") == "false"){

Thread.sleep(5000);

ctx.setTestLogicalAction(TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);

}
```